# Privacy Concerns

Tags: discussion, openid, email, faq-proposed, privacy

I am concerned about who will get access to my email on Stack Overflow and Stack Overflow Careers. I haven't found an official "privacy policy" as other sites often have.
So, how can I be assured that my email will not be redistributed outside Stack Overflow?

Note: I am concerned because I usually use a secondary email account for registrations. But this time, I used your (great) OpenID feature, but it selected by default my primary, private email, the one I usually only give out in person, and which contains my name and surname in the address.

So I would like to know who will get access to it, and I think Stack Overflow should have a policy for handling private information, or at least a mention in the FAQ.

Comment: It would be nice if a direct link existed to the privacy section of the legal stuff. Most other sites have this. I'm not saying SE should just do what other sites do, but when it comes to privacy I think most people look for that link.

Comment: There is extensive pondering on what the legal ramifications of many aspects of these sites are on the stackoverflow blog: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/legal/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The privacy policy is [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/legal/privacy-policy) (found it through the "legal" section, there indeed doesn't seem to be a direct link - but I can have overlooked it.)

Answer (score 3):

1. Click the [legal link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/legal) at the bottom of the page
2. Click the [privacy tab](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/legal/privacy-policy) on the legal section

Answer (score 1):

I guess that legal stuff is fine, but a web 2.0 project really can go beyond the legal and present this information in a way that doesn't spell CYA. Especially since privacy is a big concern on any community-generated site.

Comment: Privacy is a big concern on any *rational* community-generated site, you mean. :) I can think of a few large social sites where people seem fairly *unconcerned* about how their posts will affect future jobs, lawsuits, etc...