# Should we be informed that non-SE employees have access to profile info?

Tags: discussion, email, privacy

I came across [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229595/annotation-near-maximum-characters-causes-oops-something-bad-happened) in which a moderator noted that a user had a *"same IP diff email"*. I was under the impression that our e-mail was [only visible to us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144665/hide-email-address-from-my-profile/144667#144667) or used for the purposes explained in the input field help tip:

> [image]

I also don't see where the [privacy policy](https://stackexchange.com/legal/privacy-policy) states that moderators have access to view it. ***[** It's in the first paragraph of the "How We Use Information We Collect" section. --Ed. **]***

If this is the case, I think users should know this and moderators have different tools to determine duplicate user accounts.

Edit: it was mentioned in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/77454/195035) and [in this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149637/195035) that mod's have visibility, but it doesn't seem like it's very publicized. I'm finding this out after using the site after 3 years (perhaps I was a bit naive).

Comment: To be noted, since July 2013, [Stack Exchange logs moderator access to your 'private' information](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122801/hide-email-field-from-moderator-view-on-mobile-site/187227#187227). I don't think that access log to the user, the community team would be able to know if it's abused.

Comment: Perhaps I need to rephrase the question at this point, but I was unaware that moderators have access to my e-mail. Even if there's an agreement between moderators and StackExchange to be responsible with this information, there's no guarantee they won't misuse it (mods aren't employed by StackExchange).

Comment: @Kermit All moderators have to agree to the [moderator agreement](http://stackoverflow.com/legal/moderator-agreement) which limits what they are allowed to do with that information. Of course a rogue moderator could start scraping mail addresses, but the way SE rate limits everything I doubt they would get far.

Comment: If moderator access makes you shiver, [read this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207872/someone-contacted-me-by-email-but-my-email-is-not-public) ;-) (Nothing proven though.)

Comment: @MadScientist As I stated in my earlier comment, they're not employed by StackExchange. There is no legal requirement for them to maintain confidentiality with my e-mail address.

Comment: Actually, the privacy policy does mention this: "*When we collect your personal information, we’ll tell you how we’re using it, any types of third parties to which we might disclose it, (**other than moderators** or “agents,” such as vendors or contractors, who are only processing such information for us or at our direction)*"

Comment: Money doesn't always guarantee tight lips either

Comment: @random The law won't help me against "moderators"

Comment: Feel free to start new feature request to edit the privacy policy and make it more clear, e.g. include details from [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149637).

Comment: @Kermit That would look great on a t-shirt ;)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54311/privacy-concerns

Comment: On a more serious note, in the couple of years I've been moderating ProgSE, I can't remember a time when seeing a user's email was somehow useful. If there's a good reason we get to see user emails, I haven't yet discovered it.

Comment: I can't say how much legal authority the moderator agreement has, I suspect it has none at all. I would weigh the importance of the information against the likelihood it would be abused, and a mail address is not all that important after all. While there are probably no legal repercussions, I'd expect that I'd lose my two diamonds and probably my entire SE account if I'd misuse PII from users that I can only access because I'm a moderator.

Comment: @MadScientist In the very unlikely event that had happened, what protection do I have that it won't be abused?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but if I'm using a Google account for authentication, is there an option to stop my e-mail address from getting populated in my profile?

Comment: What sort of abuse might you be worried about?  I don't use email addresses to contact people (even in connection with my moderator duties), and selling them to marketers wouldn't be worth the trouble.

Comment: @Yannis something like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCDxP.png)?

Comment: @Kermit Probably none. If you don't trust SE and the moderators it appoints or elects, use a throwaway mail address. So many sites are hacked and information compromised recently that I wouldn't say I trust any site completely with my information. Nobody guarantees you that your information is safe, and far too many compromise your personal information by bad security practices, and this usually has  no legal consequences at all.

Comment: @Lamak: More like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5G5dp.png).

Comment: If you use gmail, then just add a period in the middle somewhere and filter anything by that straight to spam.  [e.g., `kermit@gmail.com` is identical to `ker.mit@gmail.com`, except you can filter `ker.mit@gmail.com` directly to spam.]

Comment: @Joe I'm familiar with how gmail works.

Comment: If a moderator violates the moderator agreement, SE can give them serious legal trouble.

Comment: @Pëkka It's not a contractual agreement, as far as I know.

Comment: @Emracool it is a binding agreement. Enforcement may get tricky across some national borders, but it still is an agreement and breaking it has legal consequences. Otherwise, there would be no point to it.

Comment: @Pëkka Only 18+ would be able to sign it (at least in the US), and I know of at least one <18yo US moderator. It'd be odd to accept it as not contractually binding for one person... unless there's some other arrangement?

Comment: @Emracool that's true. I wonder how they solved that. I would imagine there might be an agreement with the parents? No idea

Comment: @ShadowWizard thanks for pointing that out. I was searching for "email" in the policy. I just don't think that *"we’ll tell you how we’re using it*" has been followed.

Comment: @MadScientist It's difficult when my Google account is tied to my SE account and SE auto-populates my gmail e-mail address.